# Session userdata not updating on server codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

My problem is session userdata not updating on my server but working perfectly on my local

```
local php version :- 5.3

server php version :- 5.4
```

I am showing my sever session config

[image]

I have tried :-

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
```

and my code is :-

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_account_login',true);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_account_login_session_data',$result[0]);
```

I have checked result data `print_r($this->session->userdata);`  on local it's change every time(means updating) but on server it's stay same , any suggestion what i need to change

Comment: can you `print_r($this->session->userdata);` and post the results for both.

Comment: on server for both same but local different shows every time means updation works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes CI cannot read its own cookie file, and keeps on changing session ID. This error is practically impossible to reproduce. Me, personally have seen it only ones.
i tried following steps.

> ```
> Used DB for CI session.
> Made sure that 4k space is not exceed.
> Clearing browsers cookies manually.
> Examining PHP session cookie name and I fixed the problem by renaming CI session cookie.
> ```

Comment: Thanks @joe i am already using db for session and also done your suggested steps but still same

Comment: @Rakesh Sharma . The characters limit for user_agent coloumn in DB is 120 or more ? have u checked it ?

Comment: user_agent varchar(120)

Comment: Thanks @joe for help +1 may be useful info for others

Answer (score 1):

@Rakesh Sharma : Make sure that you have destroyed the session everytime before you create your own session userdata.